# I run a program in a shell script. How do i know if it has loaded? (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, shell, xdotool

I wrote a shell script that runs a python program. Then I want to load a file into the program using xdotool. Right now this is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Folder
python program.py &
sleep 10
WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible program)
....
```

I really don't like my solution of just waiting 10 seconds so that the program is loaded. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have your Python program start the second part of the script?

Comment: I didn't write the python program. Its a open source software

Comment: `xdotool search` has a `--sync` option that will wait for the window to become visible. If you run it with that option (i.e. `xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible program`) then your script does not need to `sleep` at all.

Comment: @ottomeister Thank You!! That was the solution to my Problem. Will it still work 100% of the time, even without sleep? I mean sometimes windows are visible but not ready?

Comment: That depends on how the program is written. Typically, by the time a window becomes visible the program has already arranged to accept and handle events that are sent into the window, so you should be safe with no sleep. If you want to be extra cautious you could sleep for a second or two after `xdotool search` returns. That's still better than the original 10 second sleep.

Comment: @ottomeister thanks a lot for your help. i tried it a few times and it seems to work. out of coution i included a one second break anyway. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

This really depends. If `program.py` is supposed to finish then go on to `xdotool` then you might want to use `&&` instead of `&`. A single `&` means you want the command to execute then move on to the next command as soon as possible without waiting for it to finish. A dobule `&&` means you want to wait for the execution to be done, then only continue if you have a zero error exit. You could also just remove the `&` or use `;` if you want to run the next command regardless of `program.py`'s success. Here's what I'm getting at:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Folder
python program.py &&
WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible program)
...
```

If `program.py` is supposed continue run while you run the `xdotool` command, but you need `program.py` to come to some ready state before you continue, then you're right in using `&`, but you need to monitor the `program.py` somehow, and get a signal from it that it is ok to continue. An ancient way of doing this is to simply let `program.py` create/touch/edit a file, and when that file is detected you continue. A more advanced way would be to use network sockets or similar, but I'd advice against it if you really don't need to do anything fancy. Anyway, if you make `program.py` create a signal file, say `/tmp/.program_signalfile`, when things are ready all you have to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/Folder
python program.py &
until [ -f /tmp/.program_signal_file ]
do
    sleep 1
done
WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible program)
rm /tmp/.program_signal_file
...
```

In this last solution `program.py` and `xdotool` are both running at the same time. If that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks what you said was really useful. I need the program to run while i run the xdotool command. But how do i make the program create a file? It is a open source software that i didn't write.

Comment: In the source code there is a line called app.MainLoop() Do I create the file right before that? But how do i create a file? Sorry I'm still pretty new to this